# Background images not loading in Android System Webview on actual TV device - any solutions?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-webview, fabricjs

I am facing one issue in Android System Webview. When updated to the latest version it is not loading any background images. It was working till early march. Earlier I thought it was due to Fabric Canvas JS but on later investigation found that when we uninstall the update for Android System Webview it is working as expected. I have tested with multiple version of Android System Webview which I am mentioning below. This issue is occurring only in Android TV actual device. Not in simulator

```
Android System Webview ==> 109.0.5414.80-541408013 ==> Working as expected
Android System Webview ==> 110.0.5481.154-548115403 ==> Working as expected
Android System Webview ==> 111.0.5563.58-556305803 ==> Break ==> March 22, 2023
```

Issue:
I have an react native app in which I am using a WebView to load the website.

```
<WebView
    cacheEnabled={false}
    cacheMode='LOAD_NO_CACHE'
    source={{ uri: url }}     //URL for Website which is develop in React JS
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    geolocationEnabled={true}
    style={{ width: widthPercentageToDP(100), height: heightPercentageToDP(120) }}
    javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically={true}
    originWhitelist={['https://*', 'git://*', 'http://*']}
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
/>
```

Inside website I am using fabric canvas js to load certain data

Website Code

```
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas();
canvas.setDimensions(this.state.canvasDimensions);
canvas.loadFromJSON(JSON.stringify(canvasJson), async function () {
    this.setState({
        imgURL: canvas.toDataURL({
            format: 'png'
        })
    })
})


render() {
    return(
        <img crossOrigin='anonymous' src={imgURL} style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} />
    )
}
```

I have tried by converting the image to blob image. It is not working. Tried with some custom image display package.